# How to add "/" in file name of Content-Disposition

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, https

I tried bellow code for giving file name when downloading a file

```
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ("dddd/aa/www.ppt"));
```

but after downloading all  "/" is replaced by "_" in the file name,this is the downloaded file name "dddd_aa_www.ppt".But I need to keep / in my file name.how can i keep this character in my file name

Comment: Can you actually save a file with `/` in the name on your PC manually?

Comment: @PaulKaram : thanks..its my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving a file with "/" is restricted.

So this is an automatic feature of that method.

I would change your naming convention to leave out these specific characters:

```
What characters can't be in a file name?
Reserved characters and words
Character   Name
\   backslash
/ slash
?   question mark
%   percent
*   asterisk or star
:   colon
|   vertical bar
"   quote
<   less than
>   greater than
.   period
    Space
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename